# iMovie: export in original size

Tags: imovie, movie

I use iMovie 9 to edit and export movies. I have some old movies, 640x480 pixels wide. When I export them, iMovie suddenly changes it to 640x360 or 960x540. Both cut off a piece of the video. Is it possible to export these movies to 640x480 somehow, or do I need another editor?

I'm waiting for Lightworks to come out, but that will probably take till summer I'm afraid. I understand iMovie 10 is a disaster, so I'm not going to upgrade to that.